# How to validate xeditable inputbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, x-editable

I am using xeditable to have inline editable functionality, but now I am stuck trying to validate my input.

Here is an example using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/93/)

I tried the below code with no success.

```
validate: function(value) {
  if($.trim(value) == '') 
    return 'This field is required';
}
```

Comment: that should work, any errors, tried printing the value of `value` to the console? Only thing I would add is the curly braces to the `if`, e.g. `if($.trim(value) == '') {
    return 'This field is required'; }`.

Comment: @ martincarlin87 Can you show me with the fiddle?

Comment: What you are trying to validate exactly ?

Comment: @faressoft Iam trying to get validate input field on submit, with warning message " This field is required ".

Comment: Do you wan't to validate on save or what ?
The validation of the name field is working fine ! The condition is always false because the id is 4 not 2.

Comment: @faressoft Yes I want to validate on save, once clicked on save if any of the field is empty i need to display that message.

Comment: @User123 alert message ? alert("please fill the required fields"); ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95583/discussion-between-user123-and-faressoft).

Comment: is this what you are trying to do - http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/11641/ ?

Comment: Thanks @M.Doye event your example is correct that is how i wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a validation function like this:

```
$scope.validateRequired = function(value) {
  if(!value)
    return "Required field";
};
```

Then use it with the event `onbeforesave`

```
onbeforesave="validateRequired($data)"
```

Please check:

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/11642/

Comment: do you have any idea how to disable Add button in the same fiddle until we click on save button so that we can not get another blank fields.

Comment: I suggests to use ng-disable="checkValid()" and inside that function check all fields if it is valid or not and return a boolean value.